# Enabling Alignment on a multi-line textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox; without using ListView or DataGridView, is there a way to align my text?

For example:

```
Column1  Column2 Column3
Test1    2a      2b
Testing2 3a      3b
```

Edit: I have tried the solution in the link provided, but I still get an output like this:

[image]

Are there some additional settings to be made to the textbox? I use the `AppendText()` function of the `TextBox` to output the text.

Comment: @GrantWinney I am still getting an issue. Please refer to my edit.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes. I used `Courier-New` with a size of `10`

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks for your help. Turns out that when I call `new Font("Courier-New", 10)`, it does not update the font; reverting to `Microsoft Sans Serif` for some reason. I had to call `new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, textbox.Font.Size)` instead, or leave the `Font` field blank.

Comment: "Courier New" does not have a dash.